# How do you debug PhotoTaskChooser in WP8 on a physical device?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have the simplest possible app. The UI is a page with nothing on it but a Tap method on a grid.

The code-behind looks like this...

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private PhotoChooserTask _photoChooser;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      _photoChooser.Completed += OnPhotoChosen;
    }

    private void OnTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {   
        _photoChooser.Show();
    }

    private void  OnPhotoChosen(object sender, PhotoResult result)
    {

    }
}
```

Now, what happens is that when I debug this application ON THE DEVICE, it briefly shows the photo chooser but then immediately deactivates...I assume because the photo chooser has taken focus. But  from everything I've read, this should NOT be happening because the PhotoChooserTask's Completed event has been wired up in the constructor for my page, which should explicitly prevent my app from deactivating when the photochooser is active.

What's even more confusing is that the app seems to work when I'm NOT debugging it. Once I've selected a photo in this scenario, my app regains the foreground.

Is this a bug with the debugger or something else?

Comment: Is this in emulator or on an actual device? Is this Real code or is this dumby code for SO?

Comment: Also are you SURE this is a windows phone 8 solution and not less? "If you are developing a Windows Phone OS 7.1 app, debugging the photo chooser task is not supported on the Windows Phone OS 7.1 emulator. " http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: This is on the device and yes that is real code, I've just removed all the extraneous stuff to make the question more focused. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the solution is to debug using "Start New Instance" in Visual Studio rather than just hitting F5.